# mark a file in Dolphin (KDE Plasma)

Tags: kde-plasma-5, kde-plasma-workspace, dolphin-file-manager

Is there any way to mark a file inside a folder to locate it easily and quickly? For example, with a mark on top of the file image.
Or to create a link/bookmark to that file in Dolphin that when I select it will show me that file in the folder that contains it.

Comment: You mean like a soft link?

Comment: Drag a document or folder to the *Places* section: https://averagelinuxuser.com/configure-dolphin-file-manager/